# Lift filter to force ssl

Tags: scala, struts, lift

in a struts application, I have a filter that forces certain pages to be accessed only over https via redirection. I'm thinking in porting it to lift so my question is: In the this environment, is there a "lift" way to implement such filter or is it similar/the same as in struts ? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Lift, the SiteMap defines the rules for page access.  You can create a SiteMap entry that does a Redirect to the https site on certain pages:

```
// create an object that does a redirect to the https server if the
// request is on http
object RequireSSL extends Loc.EarlyResponse(
  () => {
    for {
      r <- S.request
      lowLevelReq <- Box !! r if lowLevelReq.scheme == "http"
    } {
      S.redirectTo("https://"+lowLevelReq.serverName+lowLevelReq.contextPath)
    }
    Empty
  })

// Build SiteMap
def entries = (Menu("Home") / "index") ::
(Menu("Secure") / "secure" >> RequireSSL) ::
Nil
```

Hope this helps.