# Lift login form

Tags: scala, lift

I have this snippet:

```
<div width="300px">
  <form class="lift:LoginForm.logIn?form=post" id="myform">
    <fieldset>
      <input  type="email" id="l_n" name="name"/>
      <input type="password"  id="l_p"  name="password"/>
      <input type="submit"   value=">>" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

my problem is with the `name="password"` part. If I leave it as is, it is posting:

```
F811969795583JEBN3R aa@aa.com
F811969795584PURKON aaaa
F81196979558535XAIK true
F8119698955864YQEGF >>

F811969795631ROXIJO=aa%40aa.com&F811969795632SDW2QF=aaaa&F811969795633KC5QWR=true&F811969895634KA2IAC=%3E%3E
```

BUT my password field gets "unmasked" (somehow it's changing it to a regular edit field. On the other hand, my method is getting the values correctly.

If I change my HTML code this way (I changed `name='password'` to `name='pwd'`)

```
<div width="300px">
  <form class="lift:LoginForm.logIn?form=post" id="myform">
    <fieldset>
       <input  type="email" id="l_n" name="name"/>
       <input type="password"  id="l_p"  name="pwd"/>
       <input type="submit"  value=">>" />
     </fieldset>
   </form>
 </div>
```

my password field is correctly masked, but it is posting differently and I can't seem to get to "pwd" value.

```
F811969795611FN3BXU aa@aa.com 
F811969895612OASG4Z >> 
pwd                 aaaa

F811969795611FN3BXU=aa%40aa.com&pwd=aaaa&F811969895612OASG4Z=%3E%3E
```

As a newbie, I'm thoroughly confused. What am I missing? What is `name='password'` doing to my form?

I am using latest stable versions of Scala, Lift, and FoBo.

Comment: hmmm, and how would you expect the password to get masked? What do you expect as a sent data?

Comment: The password field is input type=password so I expect it to echo asterisk when someone types in, obviously. if I have name="password" that happens correctly, but if I have name="pwd" it shows up as a non-masked field (I can see the characters I'm typing. I expect to post the clear text value of the field, just not be visible in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to post your snippet in addition to the HTML for any more specifics, but I would suspect your CSS transformation is keying on the name of `pwd`, like:

```
"@password" #> SHtml.password(...)
```

That will look for any element inside the snippet invocation and replace it with a password field. When you change the name, Lift can no longer find the field to transform and you can see your original input is being submitted.

Incidentally, your other fields are also being transformed, but most likely using `SHtml.text` which will replace your input with a Lift generated input. Names like `F811969795611FN3BXU` are GUID identifiers which correspond to functions created on the Server which will be called on submit to process the value. You can see some more on that [here](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.2.html).

Comment: Thanks! While cleaning up my snippet to post, I found one place which I have previously missed. Somewhere in the code I had:
    "name=name" #> SHtml.textElem(name) &
      "name=pwd" #> (
        SHtml.textElem(pwd) ++
          SHtml.hidden(() => referer.set(r))) &
      "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(processLogIn).... and it still had name=password instead of name=pwd. Now it is posting correctly, but I'm still getting my UI field unmasked. My snippet is  from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093208/best-way-to-create-a-login-logout-form-in-scala-using-lift

Comment: Glad to help. As for your comment, try changing the `SHtml.textElem` you mentioned to `SHtml.passwordElem`. That should give you an input that masks the characters.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I should be more careful that I understand the code I copy.